# How to display pseudo element with 100% height in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element

Only Firefox seems to ignore the bottom: 0; declaration. Even when I try to set the height of the h1:before element to 100%, it won't change anything in Firefox.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour and is there any workaround out there?

[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT41k.png)

[Firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEMDS.png)

```
.title {
  position: absolute;
}
.title h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 0.8;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  border-top: 0.3em solid #0089C0;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #0089C0;
  background-color: #0089C0;
}
.title h1:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.3em;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.3em;
  top: 0;
}
.title h1:after {
  background-color: #0089C0;
}
.title h1 span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```
<div class="title">
    <h1><span>Almost before <br>we knew it, we had <br>left the ground. </span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `display:inline` from the heading - it's not required and fixes the issue - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wZebNG

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The `display:inline` is required in my case. Is there any way to fix that even with `display:inline`?

Comment: Please explain *why* it is required. From the code provided it makes no difference.

Comment: `display: inline-block` should work if you really need it *inline*..

Comment: Maybe use other type of inline like `inline-block`.

Comment: I updated my question. I'd like to do something like that and therefore I need the `display:inline`.

Comment: Please note that pseudo elements now use two colons, not one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: Cheat! - put the pseudo-element in relation to the div - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MRoNvg

Comment: This comes pretty close. Thanks Paulie_D. It still looks different somehow in Firefox but I will try to figure out if this can be adjusted. Thanks to Rob as well for reminding me of the double colons. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.title h1` to `display: inline-block;` like this:

```
.title h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or...set the `position` to `fixed` like this:

```
.title h1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. In my case `display:inline` is required. Is there a way to fix this anyway?

Comment: Updated my answer to include a different approach where the `display: inline;` is preserved.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in my case. The `<h1>` content doesn't look like marked text anymore, when I change it to `position: fixed`.

Comment: So just to confirm, you've set `position: fixed;` and `display: inline;` and you're still getting this issue?

Comment: Firefox recognizes the height correctly but the text doesn't look like marked text anymore. Take a look at Paulie_D's approach in the comments below my question. This comes pretty close.